# ListsActivity not updating after broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, listactivity

in simple words, I'd like that my SMS list updates every time I get a new SMS. Here's the code

```
    static String phoneNumber;
    int phoneID;
    private ListSMSAdapter adapter_1;
    public List<SMSData> smsList = new ArrayList<SMSData>();
    private PhoneDAO dao;

    private BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Log.i("MESSAGE", Integer.toString(smsList.size()));
            smsList.clear();
            smsList.addAll(fillSMS(phoneNumber));
            Log.i("MESSAGE", Integer.toString(smsList.size()));
            adapter_1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dao = new PhoneDAO(this);

        Bundle showData = getIntent().getExtras();
        phoneNumber = showData.getString("phone_number");
        phoneID = showData.getInt("phone_id");

        adapter_1 = new ListSMSAdapter(this, fillSMS(phoneNumber));
        setListAdapter(adapter_1);
    }

    protected List<SMSData> fillSMS(String p){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "address = \"" + p + "\"", null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // Read the sms data and store it in the list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                SMSData sms = new SMSData();
                sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
                sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                smsList.add(sms);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        return smsList;
    }
```

By now the first log show: 5 **(it should display 6)**

after the addAll : 10

but even after that the list of SMS is not updating. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The receiver IS working, sorry for not pointing that out.

The problem seems to be inside updateReceiver with "clear" and "addAll"

Answer (score 0):

I do not see it in your code snippet, did you ever call [registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) giving your `updateReceiver`? Or likewise, using the `<receiver>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, the receiver is working (I've updated the question)

Comment: One thing that does stand out is that BroadcastReceiver updates the list twice. Once in `fillSMS`, and then doubles it with the call to `addAll()` given itself.

Comment: Yep, clear() will clear it from the previous broadcast. But within the same onReceive, you are doubling the list. It happens in one line `smsList.addAll(fillSMS(phoneNumber));`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modification in your code please check

```
static String phoneNumber;
int phoneID;
private ListSMSAdapter adapter_1;
public List<SMSData> smsList = new ArrayList<SMSData>();
private PhoneDAO dao;

private BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.i("MESSAGE", Integer.toString(smsList.size()));
        smsList.clear();
        fillSMS(phoneNumber);
        Log.i("MESSAGE", Integer.toString(smsList.size()));
        adapter_1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dao = new PhoneDAO(this);

    Bundle showData = getIntent().getExtras();
    phoneNumber = showData.getString("phone_number");
    phoneID = showData.getInt("phone_id");
    fillSMS(phoneNumber);
    adapter_1 = new ListSMSAdapter(this, smsList);
    setListAdapter(adapter_1);
}

protected List<SMSData> fillSMS(String p){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "address = \"" + p + "\"", null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            SMSData sms = new SMSData();
            sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
            sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
            smsList.add(sms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```